# Convert string into date time stamp in gawk or awk

Tags: awk, gawk

I want to convert following string (**20140805234656**) into date time stamp (**2014-08-05 23:46:56**).I am new to gawk and I don't know the exact syntax,how can I put **-** at every 5,8 and **:** at every 14,17 and put " " at 11 index. Is there any efficient way to achieve  this in awk?

**EDIT**

Please note that I have string as variable in awk.I generated it during some processing of records.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One way of doing it using GNU awk is this:

```
echo 20140805234656 | awk 'BEGIN { FIELDWIDTHS = "4 2 2 2 2 2" } { printf "%s-%s-%s %s:%s:%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6 }'
```

Comment: Ah. This is a much efficienter way! Nicely done.

Comment: @Subbeh thanks for your answer,can u suggest how can i use FIELDWIDTH with variable.

Comment: @user2801682, `$0 = your_variable`

Answer (score 10):

You can use substring as follow:

```
echo 20140805234656 | awk '{print substr($0,1,4)"-"substr($0,5,2)"-"substr($0,7,2)" "substr($0,9,2)":"substr($0,11,2)":"substr($0,13,2) }'
```

Probably there are easier ways too.

Comment: This one has the benefit of being standard/portable.

Comment: Ah, cool. Thanks for reviewing and fixing the offset!

Answer (score 7):

Another GNU awk answer

```
gawk -v timestamp=20140805234656 '
    BEGIN {
        if (match(timestamp, /(....)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)/, m)) {
            t = mktime(m[1] " " m[2] " " m[3] " " m[4] " " m[5] " " m[6])
            print strftime("%F %T", t)
            print strftime("%c", t) 
        }
    }
'
```

```
2014-08-05 23:46:56
Tue Aug  5 23:46:56 2014
```

Answer (score 5):

Another GNU `awk` approach:

```
result = gensub("(....)(..)(..)(..)(..)", "\\1-\\2-\\3 \\4:\\5:", 1, your_variable)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
echo 20140805234656 | awk ' { printf "%s-%s-%s %s:%s:%s", 
                                     substr($0,1,4),
                                     substr($0,5,2),
                                     substr($0,7,2),
                                     substr($0,9,2),
                                     substr($0,11,2),
                                     substr($0,13,2)
                             } '
```

Or, if you want to asign it to a variable first:

```
echo 20140805234656 | awk ' { d=sprintf ("%s-%s-%s %s:%s:%s", 
                                     substr($0,1,4),
                                     substr($0,5,2),
                                     substr($0,7,2),
                                     substr($0,9,2),
                                     substr($0,11,2),
                                     substr($0,13,2));
                              print "Date is: " d
                             } '
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
$ echo 20140805234656 |
  awk '{split($0,a,"");printf("%s-%s-%s %s:%s:%s\n",a[1]a[2]a[3]a[4],a[5]a[6],a[7]a[8],a[9]a[10],a[11]a[12],a[13]a[14])}'
2014-08-05 23:46:56
```

Comment: It is not portable. The behaviour with an empty separator is unspecified by POSIX and in practice, it doesn't work with the original awk or nawk.

Answer (score 0):

I have a question
I have a text file that I want to use awk to change the date part and put the current date
Of course, I wrote this and it works, but I have to give it the date manually, and what I want is for it to automatically replace the day's date.

Code :
awk '{gsub(/ISODate("[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][-][0-9][0-9][-][0-9][0-9]/,"ISODate("2022-10-02");print}' rasoul-02.json

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/424993)

Comment: This is a question, please delete and ask in another thread.